# Why is PrimeNg dialog (V9.1.3) not centered in IE11?

Tags: angular, primeng

I have an Angular 9.0.2 application with PrimeNg 9.1.3.

I use the dialog modal component. It runs fine in Chrome and Edge, not a surprise.

But in IE11 when the modal is displayed the messagebox is on the right of the screen.
When I click on the messagebox it moves to the center.

I tried to set [position] = "center" but it did not help

I did uncomment import 'classlist.js'; in my polyfills.ts file

In tsconfig.json I target "ES5" and lib is set to "es2018"

This is my dialog code, it can't be much simpler then that

```
<p-dialog header="TEST" [visible]="true" [closable]="false" [closeOnEscape]="false" [modal]="true" [position]="center">
    Some test to center
</p-dialog>
```

How can I get it to center in IE11?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in this stack blitz please. https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dialog-close-g6rygp?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: I can't even open stackblitz in IE11